# Can graph be zoomed and shows respective data?

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter application which has a graph data in it .The data for the graph is dynamic and real time and is fetched from server . What i want is that the graph can be zoomed and in zooming the graph the application should show the respective data from the zoomed portion ? Can this be achieved in flutter ? If yes then how can i do this ? Please provide me some overview. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423707/flutter-zoomable-widget

Comment: GestureDetector can help with this but can u tell me how can i get the zoomed portion using gesture detector because after zooming i have to show all the hidden data of that specific portion