# BoxFit.cover does not work with CachedNetworkImage plus PhotoView

Tags: flutter

In this scenario I can not make to work the fit property with BoxFit.cover.
There is always borders on screen. How can I do it?

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: CachedNetworkImage(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    fit: BoxFit.cover, // does not work
    imageUrl: _imageUrl,
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => PhotoView(
      imageProvider: imageProvider,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I think there are no oracles to know what is PhotoView

Comment: @someuser https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future searchers, there is an another solution which seems perfectly fits the desired behaviour.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200356/5829191

Answer (score 0):

```
       Container(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: _imageUrl,
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider)=>PhotoView(
            minScale: 1.0,
            imageProvider: imageProvider,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: please add some instructions or just a few words so @rozerro can learn something here

Comment: @BrettSchneider anyway, this answer is wrong, because the answerer didn't check it out

Comment: ok, that's not for me to decide. i'm just on review duty

Comment: I suppose that with PhotoView it's impossible or hard to ahive the classic behaviour of `cover` option, or there will always should be some intial zoom value.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. Since I have a Container with the same borderRadius as the Catched Image. Without the BoxDecoration it failed med too!

```
    Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: 
BorderRadius.circular(10),),child:CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: ("UrlToImage"),imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvider,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            )),),placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset("PathToImage")
                                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Chache into a SizedBox and set its height and width to double.maxFinite, this will solve your problem. This is the solution given on their git thread, Hope it helps someone.

```
SizedBox(
        height: double.maxFinite,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: _imageUrl,,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
```

Giving height and width to the CachedNetworkImage widget itself self not seem to be working.

More Details: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/134