# Flutter: enable image zoom in/out on double tap using InteractiveViewer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, zooming

I want to enable zoom in and out on double tap of the image, together with scaling in/out on pinch.
I saw some tutorials on YouTube where they implemented this feature using `GestureDetector` like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJqtDDtxJHI) but for some reason, it didn't work out for me.
In order to implement scaling in/out on pinch, I relied on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287892/13727011), and it really works well, but I also want to enable zoom in/out on double tapping the image. Looking up a way to do so on the internet, unfortunately, yielded nothing.

Is there any way to enable zoom in/out with both pinch and double tap using `InteractiveViewer`?

here is my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: InteractiveViewer(
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(80),
      panEnabled: false,
      scaleEnabled: true,
      minScale: 1.0,
      maxScale: 2.2,
      child: Image.network("https://pngimg.com/uploads/muffin/muffin_PNG123.png",
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: yes, you need to use `TransformationController`

Comment: @pskink If I use the `TransformationController`, how can I know that the user double-tapped the image? Wrapping the image or the `InteractiveViewer` with `GestureDetector` doesn't work. There are no examples of this on the internet. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: it works just fine: `child: GestureDetector(
onDoubleTapDown: (d) => print('onDoubleTapDown ${d.localPosition}'),
onDoubleTap: () => print('onDoubleTap'),
child: InteractiveViewer( ...
`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use a `GestureDetector`, that gives you the position of the click and with that you can zoom with the `TransformationController` at the click position:

```dart
final _transformationController = TransformationController();
TapDownDetails _doubleTapDetails;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onDoubleTapDown: (d) => _doubleTapDetails = d,
    onDoubleTap: _handleDoubleTap,
    child: Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: _transformationController,
        /* ... */
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void _handleDoubleTap() {
  if (_transformationController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
    _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity();
  } else {
    final position = _doubleTapDetails.localPosition;
    // For a 3x zoom
    _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
      ..translate(-position.dx * 2, -position.dy * 2)
      ..scale(3.0);
    // Fox a 2x zoom
    // ..translate(-position.dx, -position.dy)
    // ..scale(2.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Firstly, thank you for your answer. Secondly, notice that `transformationController` isn't defined `GestureDetector` so this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks you are right, the `transformationController` is the argument of the `InteractiveViewer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works excellently! I hope you don't mind if I ask - is there a way I can control the animation of it? for example, I want to set a specific duration and curve for the zoom in/out.

Comment: Why did you use `-2x` for `translate` and `3` as `scale` multiplication value?
I would really appreciate if you provide any mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 14):

To animate the transition on double tap, you have to create an explicit animation on top of [Till's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634589/14521881).

```
class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  .
  .
  .  
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Matrix4> _animation;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    )..addListener(() {
        _transformationController.value = _animation.value;
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  .
  .
  .
  void _handleDoubleTap() {
    Matrix4 _endMatrix;
    Offset _position = _doubleTapDetails.localPosition;

    if (_transformationController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
      _endMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
    } else {
      _endMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-_position.dx * 2, -_position.dy * 2)
        ..scale(3.0);
    }

    _animation = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: _endMatrix,
    ).animate(
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut).animate(_animationController),
    );
    _animationController.forward(from: 0);
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, when I double tap on the image it does not respond to the gestures and does not zoom in or out.

Comment: Just a reminder, the above code is the pieces you have to add or change to @Till's code. It won't work on its own. Highlighting the changes, 1) include the mixin in the class 2) add _animationController and _animation 3) override the initState and dispose function, include the _transformationController in these function as well 4) replace the _handleDoubleTap function. The _handleDoubleTapDown should remain in the class. Make sure you include the correct _transformationController in your build function, if you simply missed the underscore.

Comment: Most likely it is your _transformationController screwing things up.

Comment: In flutter-2.0, to fix the UnimplementedError of scale function, you need to fix scale(3) to scale(3.0).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a full, portable solution with included customizable animation:

```dart
class DoubleTappableInteractiveViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  final double scale;
  final Duration scaleDuration;
  final Curve curve;
  final Widget child;
  
  const DoubleTappableInteractiveViewer({
    super.key,
    this.scale = 2,
    this.curve = Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
    required this.scaleDuration,
    required this.child,
  });
  
  @override
  State<DoubleTappableInteractiveViewer> createState() => _DoubleTappableInteractiveViewerState();
}

class _DoubleTappableInteractiveViewerState extends State<DoubleTappableInteractiveViewer>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Matrix4>? _zoomAnimation;
  late TransformationController _transformationController;
  TapDownDetails? _doubleTapDetails;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _transformationController = TransformationController();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.scaleDuration,
    )..addListener(() {
      _transformationController.value = _zoomAnimation!.value;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _transformationController.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  void _handleDoubleTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
  _doubleTapDetails = details;
}

  void _handleDoubleTap() {
    final newValue = 
      _transformationController.value.isIdentity() ?
        _applyZoom() : _revertZoom();
      
    _zoomAnimation = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: newValue,
    ).animate(
      CurveTween(curve: widget.curve)
        .animate(_animationController)
    );
    _animationController.forward(from: 0);
  }
  
  Matrix4 _applyZoom() {
    final tapPosition = _doubleTapDetails!.localPosition;
    final translationCorrection = widget.scale - 1;
    final zoomed = Matrix4.identity()
      ..translate(
        -tapPosition.dx * translationCorrection,
        -tapPosition.dy * translationCorrection,
      )
      ..scale(widget.scale);
    return zoomed;
  }
  
  Matrix4 _revertZoom() => Matrix4.identity();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTapDown: _handleDoubleTapDown,
      onDoubleTap: _handleDoubleTap,
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: _transformationController,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```dart
DoubleTappableInteractiveViewer(
  scaleDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
  child: Image.network(imageUrl),
),
```

Play around with it on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/bc14993b89331788667eebc0e311702c).