# How to set InteractiveViewer initial zoom level

Tags: flutter, zooming, interactive

I am using InteractiveViewer to display a video. It is working properly.
But I want set initial zoom level.

Is there a way to do this?

```
return InteractiveViewer(
  minScale: 1,
  maxScale: 4,
  constrained: false,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 320,
    height: 180,
    child: widget.remoteVideoRenderer(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: use `TransformationController? transformationController` parameter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to do this, with varying levels of success, like so (credit to @pskink for pointing me in the right direction):

```dart
  final viewTransformationController = TransformationController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    final zoomFactor = 2.0;
    final xTranslate = 300.0;
    final yTranslate = 300.0;
    viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(0, 0, zoomFactor);
    viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(1, 1, zoomFactor);
    viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(2, 2, zoomFactor);
    viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(0, 3, -xTranslate);
    viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(1, 3, -yTranslate);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: viewTransformationController,
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 6,
              child: // ....
    );
  }
```

`viewTransformationController.value` is a 4x4 matrix that is applied to the view, it encodes the translations/rotations/scaling. The representation of these transformations in the matrix is probably documented somewhere (and/or just standard from projective/affine geometry), but I couldn't find them, so I just printed them out while zooming/panning until the roles of each entry became clear.

If you just set the zoom factor to 2 and don't translate, you'll be zoomed-in on the top-left corner of the widget.

Note that you cannot access the windows dimensions in the `initState()` method using `MediaQuery.of(context)`, which is somewhat inconvenient if you want to e.g. zoom in on the middle of the window. I haven't found a good way to do that yet.

Comment: This is working for me and should be the accepted answer! Saved me hours of headache! Thanks!

Comment: To use the context at the start you just have to put um method inside a WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, so your method will be call after the screen setup, just after the first frame.

Comment: You can refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408346/flutter-enable-image-zoom-in-out-on-double-tap-using-interactiveviewer). It has shortcuts/simpler methods for working with Matrix4.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
 final scaleMatrix = Matrix4.identity()..scale(0.3);
          final viewTransformationController =
              TransformationController(scaleMatrix);
 
InteractiveViewer(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                transformationController: viewTransformationController,
```

Comment: The `alignment` property seems to be ignored with `constrained: false,`.

Answer (score 2):

Base on Amos Joshua answer, if you want to always zoom center screen. I have this formula:

```
zoomFactor = 1, xTrans = 0, yTrans = 0
zoomFactor = 2, xTrans = w / 2, yTrans = h / 2
zoomFactor = 2.8, xTrans = (w / 2)(1 + 0.8), yTrans = (h / 2)(1 + 0.8)
```

Therefore:

```
zoomFactor = z, xTrans = (w / 2)(z - 1), yTrans = (h / 2)(z - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Amos answer (thanks!) Here's my formula for centering the image on screen:

```
void setInitialViewTransformation(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
  final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  const imageSize = 1024.0;
  final zoomFactor = screenWidth / imageSize;

  const xTranslate = 00.0;
  final yTranslate =
    -(constraints.maxHeight - imageSize * zoomFactor) / 2 + (screenHeight - constraints.maxHeight) / 2;

  viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(0, 0, zoomFactor);
  viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(1, 1, zoomFactor);
  viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(2, 2, zoomFactor);
  viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(0, 3, -xTranslate);
  viewTransformationController.value.setEntry(1, 3, -yTranslate);
}
```

`constraints` are achieved through LayoutBuilder to give sense of parent width/height.

The y translate portion centers and compensates for appbar and other views not in current view